# Django escape only certain HTML tags

Tags: python, html, django

Is it possible to escape all html tags except for the  tag somehow?

I am sending a user entered string from a view to an html template where I have manually added  tags to the string in the view. I would like to allow for that to be shown, but of course omit all html tags entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is that you could write your own filter to do this.

A better solution IMHO would be to remove any tags from your user input, then add whatever tags you want, and then use the "safe" filter to display your modified text.